# Getting error "error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host" while connecting to database hosted in RDS from lambda

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Here is code in my lambda function

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("hereeeeee");
  const dbConfig = {
    host: ENDPOINT_URL,
    port: 5432,
    database: DATABASE_NAME,
    user: USERNAME,
  };

  const signer = new Signer({
    region: MY_REGION,
    hostname: ENDPOINT_URL,
    port: dbConfig.port,
    username: dbConfig.user,
  });

  try {
    const token = await signer.getAuthToken();
    console.log("Generated token");
    dbConfig.password = token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  const client = new Client(dbConfig);

  try {
    await client.connect();

    console.log("Connected");

    const query = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name;";
    const result = await client.query(query);

    console.log(result);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.rows),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "Error fetching data from the database",
      }),
    };
  } finally {
    await client.end();
  }
};
```

My lambda and RDS are in same VPC. I have given necessary IAm permissions to my lambda to connect to RDS. But when i try to run the lambda each time i get error

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "49.43.242.150", user "username", database "databasename", no encryption
.
.
.
.
.
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 162,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '543',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
}
```

RDS allows connection from all hosts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzbba.png)

I was trying to connect to database and fetch data but keep getting same error. I tried connecting using password as well as IAM.

Comment: Is that the only error message?  Usually (with libpq programs) you will get two errors, one saying that with ssl failed, and the other saying that without ssl also failed.  What you showed is only the 2nd of those.